# How to enable IAP for services with canary deployment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress

I am trying to do a canary deployment in GKE. I need to enable IAP for all the deployments in this.

I can build the canary using both Istio and nginx-ingress for my usecase. But I cant figure how to enable IAP for the either of them. I provisioned a GLB (Global HTTP load balancer) and tried to add the ingresses as backends in both cases. That failed as I expected because health checks and things didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an HTTPS load balancer to be able to enable IAP. You can click on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-kubernetes-howto#before_you_begin) which provides step by step instructions on how to enable IAP within GKE. I would also highly suggest reading the section “Before you begin” as you will need the prerequisites mentioned to enable IAP.